# Change default text color in Bash/Zsh

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, zsh

What I want to do is to set the default color (like if output `\e[0m`) for EVERY output. For some reasons I can’t change it in terminal settings and only hope that Bash can

One way I think it might be possible is to redirect output to temporary file (or file descriptor, or function if possible) and print everything char-by-char or something and removing the reset sequence, but I’m not sure it’s the best way

So can Bash or Zsh do it quickly?

Comment: I guess you mean _for EVERY output **which is sent to the terminal**_. Still then, it is unclear whether you are refering to stdout, or stderr, or both. I'm not aware of any shell which would support this kind of transformation. Such a general feature would be problematic anyway: What should be the behaviour, if you run a program which prints to stdout already its own colouring escape sequences (example `ls -color=auto`)? If you want colourful output, the application producing the output should do this (at least when it is talking to a terminal), similar to the behavious of `ls`.

Comment: I want a general way for that so I can switch it on and off for both stdout and stderr separately or not — doesn’t really matter. About `ls`, as I said in post, I want to replace only default color — other ones will stay as the program wants. And the thing is that I want to recollect the whole shell so the simple `echo` will be red, blue or whatever I’ll told it by default, without ` -e “\e[31m”`

Comment: You could write  a wrapper which invokes an arbitrary command, collects the output and write it with colouring information to stdout, if you want. I just can't imagine that this is really useful.

Comment: If you don't want to reinvent the wheel, you could steal code from [lolcat](https://pypi.org/project/lolcat/), It does something similar, except that instead of collecting the output from a child process, it takes it from its own stdin.

Comment: As I said in the post, I can’t set terminal theme in settings (one is TTY, and the other one just does not allow this). It’d be great if I could set theme using shell only

Comment: Since this feature is not provided by any bash implementation I know of, you could try to post a change request for the maintainers of bash or zsh.